# ASP MVC does not validate model

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-mvc-4

There is a simple view:

```
@model Bla.SomeModel

<div class="soket-item">
    <form>
        <div class="form-group socket-info-group">
            <label asp-for="Count" class="control-label"></label>
            <input name="Sockets[@index].Count" asp-for="Count" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="Count" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <input type="submit" value="Push!" />
    </form>
</div>
```

And there is a simple model :

```
public class SomeModel
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Charge Count")]
    [Range(1, 10)]
    public int Count { get; set; }
}
```

[image]

As I set Range attribute I expect a warning to appear when a negative value entering. But that doesn't happen.
Why ?

[image]

**UPD** Controller :

```
namespace Bla.Controllers
{
    [Route("Socket")]
    public class MyController : Controller
    {
        [Route("New")]
        public ActionResult NewSocketForm()
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Share your controller method please.

Comment: I added the updated code below

Comment: You are not validating your model then how it would validate. Please [visit](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/mvc/implement-validation-in-asp.net-mvc) to understand how model validation works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the updated code:

**Code for UI**

```
@model SomeModel

<div class="soket-item">
    <form asp-controller="Home" asp-action="New" method="post" >
        <div class="form-group socket-info-group">
            <label asp-for="Count" class="control-label"></label>
            <input name="Count" type="text" asp-for="Count" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="Count" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <input type="submit" value="Push!" />
    </form>
</div>
```

**Code for Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult New(SomeModel someModel)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        ViewBag.ErrorMessage = "Invalid Input";
    }
    // do your things
    return View("Index");
}
```